# mSATA to USB for 2.4Ghz Wireless Peripherals

Tags: usb, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, msata

On my laptop, I have an [mSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) SSD that I am not using. Would it be possible to get a piece of hardware to convert mSATA to USB so that I could plug a 2.4Ghz wireless receiver for a keyboard and/or mouse into it to free up a USB port on the outside of the laptop?

I am encountering a few issues with this. First, I have yet to find hardware that goes from mSATA to USB. All I have been able to find is an [image of something that may work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRikE.jpg) - although, I cannot find its source and its form factor would not fit in my laptop. Does something like this actually exist in the correct form factor?

My second concern, would the computer even recognize the USB port and allow the 2.4Ghz receiver to function properly?

My last question is, would there be too much interference or physical obstructions to allow the 2.4Ghz receiver to function correctly from within the laptop?

Comment: Why don't you just use a USB Hub instead?  You can get a 4-port USB Hub for about 1/100 of the cost of the hardware you are talking about.  Besides you can't just install a 2.4Ghz wireless receiver and expect a keyboard and mouse to be able to communicate with it.  In most cases those devices don't communicate in plain text.

Comment: I have a laptop that I carry around and would rather not have to carry around the hub too. And I am using a Logitech Unifying receiver with two logitech devices.

Comment: Yes; Logitech often uses recievers that encrypt the communications with their devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot work, because S-ATA is a storage interface while USB is a universal bus. You can “convert” USB to S-ATA, but not vice versa.

Do not be confused by PCIe Mini Card adapters. While PCIe Mini Card does indeed carry USB, mSATA does not. Because it is not PCIe Mini Card, it just uses the same connector.

Comment: I was guessing that this would be the case. Thanks for clarifying.